# how can use Primefaces incell editing with selectonemenu with object

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a selectOneMenu with a list of objects of type SelectItem,
how to use a selectOneMenu with a list of objects within
one cell editing.
When rendering the page loads the data but to change the Sucursalesin the cell editing shows me the following util.SucursalUtil @ 52d68a, how could I display the appropriate value.

```
<p:column headerText="Sucursal" style="width:25%">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.nombreSucursal}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.nombreSucursal}" style="width:100%">
            <f:selectItems value="#{clientesMB.itemsSucursal}" var="man" itemLabel="#{man}"
                           itemValue="#{man}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

`private List<SelectItem> itemsSucursal = new LinkedList<SelectItem>();`

---

---

Now code look like this

```
<p:column headerText="Sucursal" style="width:25%">  
                                <p:cellEditor>  
                                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.nombreSucursal}" /></f:facet>  
                                    <f:facet name="input">  
                                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.sucBanc}" style="width:100%" converter="sucursalConverter">  
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{clientesMB.itemsSucursal}"/>  
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>  
                                    </f:facet>  
                                </p:cellEditor>  
                            </p:column>
```

---

```
 <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{clientesMB.modiCell}" update=":form2:formgen" />
```

---

```
 public void modiCell(CellEditEvent event) throws Exception {
    try {
        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
        //SucursalUtnewValueil c = (SucursalUtil) event.getNewValue();
        int row = event.getRowIndex();
        this.empClienteEditar.getCuentasBancarias().get(row).setNombreSucursal(newValue.toString());
        if (newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + row + ", New:" + newValue);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, "Error: modiCliente() " + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

---

that´ the problem, when change value the first time show in the table the id of object (a number), dont´ show the label...

Comment: Looks like `itemsSucursal` is not a `List<String>` object. Since you have this, you must override the `toString()` method in this class in order to show properly. By the way, I would recommend not using `var="man" itemValue="#{man}"` since the `String` result maybe it's not the best way to identify the selected value.

Comment: it work, <h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.sucBanc}"  sucBanc type is the same of the list of values, it using converter, but when chanche value show the id value of the objetc... in actionlistener call this  this.empClienteEditar.getCuentasBancarias().get(row).setNombreSucursal(newValue.toString());, this is working but show the id in when reder table...

Comment: Would you like to update your question and add the new code and describe the new problem?